# How to hide data using radio button after page onload in php or jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

In my program have radio buttons for selecting specific event or all events. this my code is

index.php:

```
      <tr>
            <td width="15%" align="left">View entry statistics<span class="mandetory_text">*</span></td>
            <td width="2%" align="left" valign="middle">:</td>
            <td width="1%"><input name="e_access" id="e_access_<?php echo $edit_row['id'];  ?>"  type="radio" value="yes"  <?php if($edit_row['access_status']=='yes')  {?> checked="checked" <?php }?> /></td>
            <td width="11%">Permitted</td>
            <td width="1%"><input name="e_access" id="e_access_<?php echo $edit_row['id'];  ?>" type="radio" value="true" <?php if($edit_row['access_status']=='true')  {?>  checked="checked" <?php }?> /></td>
            <td width="13%">Not permitted</td>
            <td width="60%"></td>
            </tr>
```

this code is using for creating and editing an event. So when i am creating event default all events radio button is checked. And also for specific radio button click display one table need chance for selecting some events up to here it is fine but when i am edit this same event all the data displayed in this page here i want is if create with all events radio button no need to display table as the same way create with specific events(radio button) need to show table what are the events are selected and tick mark(select) radio button. for this i am write a code in script

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function()   {
    var selected =  $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();

    if(selected == 'all')
     {
     $(".edit_veri_table").hide();
      }
    });
   </script>
```

but in edit page radio buttons(all events and specific events) are showing properly when the page is load display the table(if already selected in specific event button).

when specific button click display table and all events button click hide the table how can i do it please..

Comment: Didn't got you. You requirements are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

> when specific button click display table

If you simply want to show on a specific button and hide on rest then you can try this:(*demo consists a static dataset*)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").on("click",function(){
 if(this.id == "show"){
     $(".table").show();
 }else{
   $(".table").hide();
 }
 
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


</script>
<table class='table'>
<tr>
            <td width="15%" align="left">View entry statistics<span class="mandetory_text">*</span></td>
            <td width="2%" align="left" valign="middle">:</td>
            <td width="1%"><input name="e_access" id="e_access_1"  type="radio" value="yes"   checked="checked" /></td>
            <td width="11%">Permitted</td>
            <td width="1%"><input name="e_access" id="e_access_2;  ?>" type="radio" value="true" /></td>
            <td width="13%">Not permitted</td>
            <td width="60%"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <button id="show">SHOW</button> <button id="hide">HIDE!!</button> <button id="hide1">HIDE!</button>
```

**NOTE:** You should have always `unique id's` on the page.So:

```
            <td width="1%"><input name="e_access" id="e_access_<?php echo $edit_row['id'];  ?>"  type="radio" value="yes"  <?php if($edit_row['access_status']=='yes')  {?> checked="checked" <?php }?> /></td>
            <td width="1%"><input name="e_access" id="e_access_<?php echo $edit_row['id'];  ?>" type="radio" value="true" <?php if($edit_row['access_status']=='true')  {?>  checked="checked" <?php }?> /></td>
```

are `not valid` since they both will have `same ids`.either `use class` or make sure to `create unique` ids.